# Why do Python floats have real and imag attributes?

Tags: python

At least in Python 3, `float` has attributes `real` and `imag`, and a method `conjugate()`. Since `issubclass(float, complex)` evaluates to `False`, what is the reason for these?

Comment: Are you asking for a practical reason or a philosophical one?

Comment: @norok2 Well now I'm interested in both.

Comment: I'd say I'm philosophically wondering if there is a practical reason for their existence!

Comment: Just for completeness, so does `int`, as well as `denominator` and `numerator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is obviously a design choice and it is very well rooted in Python numeric types (i.e. `bool`, `int`, `float`, `complex`), as clear from the source code (e.g. for [`float`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c)).

This has been discussed in [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/), which resulted in the [`numbers` module for **Numeric abstract base classes**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html) module.
As you can see, `.real`, `.imag` and `.conjugate()` are part of the generic `Number` abstraction.

From a practical perspective, this means that any numeric algorithm can be safely written for `complex` and it will gracefully work for any `Number` subtype.